# Не срабатывает метод ViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback()

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

У меня есть Pager основанный на фрагментах, т.к. всего 3 страницы. И при скроле у меня разная высота контента и Pager ее обрезает. Решил обойти это сделав метод который активируется по идее, когда сменилась страница, но не срабатывает по какой то причине(Без метода код с высотой работает)?! Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Код MainActivity.kt:

```
        slider.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            super.onPageSelected(position)
            val view = slider
                view.post {
                    val wMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
                    val hMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
                    view.measure(wMeasureSpec, hMeasureSpec)

                    if (slider.layoutParams.height != view.measuredHeight) {
                        // ParentViewGroup is, for example, LinearLayout
                        // ... or whatever the parent of the ViewPager2 is
                        slider.layoutParams = (slider.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams)
                            .also { lp -> lp.height = view.measuredHeight }
                    }
                }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Сложно судить с таким неймингом где конекретно проблемы, но есть такие идеи:

1. Убедиться что функция точно не вызывается с помощью логов.

Если проблема в этом, то попробовать реализовать функцию **onPageSelected(position: Int)** и использовать её.

2. Если функция всё же вызывается, то попробовать вызывать изменения в UI **post**. Вроде:

   post {
   slider.layoutParams.height = 100
   }
3. Нашёл вот такую тему, где в комментах предлагают готовое решение. Можно скопипастить:

[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58492796/viewpager2-with-differing-item-heights-and-wrap-content)

Comment: Спасибо, я изначально его и использовал(это решение), просто потом все подряд стал пробовать и залил это. Я от туда убрал все и оставил для проверки только изменение высоты. Такой вопрос, там VIEW - это ViewPager или Layout в котором он находится?

Comment: @REDOO Если правильно понял вопрос, то ViewPager.
Вообще очень рекомендую переходить на Compose. Там почти нет боли с ViewPager и даже RecyclerView. Его можно прикручивать только для отдельных экранов. Например реализовать на нём именно этот кейс, про который был задан вопрос

Comment: Спасибо, рассмотрю...

Comment: Изменил код в вопросе, сделал как было, но все равно не работает

Comment: У ViewPager2 height на xml равна wrap_content?

Comment: Да, установлено

Comment: Еще вариант попробовать у корневого View фрагментов (которые внутри ViewPager2) вызывать .requestLayout в onResume()

Comment: Я поковырял compose и понял, что лучше я изучу его, чем буду мучаться здесь. Спасибо вам за помощь !

Comment: Хороший выбор. Удачи!